# SAS X command - Trying to execute mkdir with spaces in path

Tags: cmd, sas

In windows sas 9.4, I'm trying to use the Using X command to create a folder using mkdir.  Is it possible to do this if the path contains spaces?

Trying to set this up before a proc printto for logs and listings.  Test code posted below seems to fail because of the spaces.

```
    options mprint compress=yes reuse=yes;

    %let qtr=%str(2);
    %let yr=%str(2012);
    %let logout=%str(program_name_&yr.&qtr._&sysdate.);

    %let logname=%str(C:\Users\doe_j\folder\sub-folder1\sub folder2\subfolder3 &yr.\q&qtr.\logs\&logout..log);

    %let logfolder=%str(C:\Users\doe_j\foler\sub-folder1\sub folder2\subfolder3 &yr.\q&qtr.\logs);

    x "if not exist ""&logfolder.\"" mkdir -p &logfolder.";
```

Comment: Have you tried `mkdir ""&logfolder.""`? What is `-p` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close. It looks like the second occurrence of `&logfolder` in the `X` statement needs to be surrounded by escaped double quotes just as the first occurrence is. The slightly edited code below works for me:

```
options noxwait mprint symbolgen compress=yes reuse=yes;

%let qtr=%str(2);
%let yr=%str(2012);
%let logout=%str(program_name_&yr.&qtr._&sysdate.);
%let logfolder=%str(C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\sub-folder1\sub folder2 space\year &yr.\q&qtr.\logs);
%let logname=%str(&logfolder.\&logout..log);

x "if not exist ""&logfolder."" mkdir ""&logfolder.""";
```

Comment: Thanks @Hugs.  Your code worked for me too.  I personally preferred the other solution, but either works.

Answer (score 1):

I think that adding quote marks to the *logfolder* variable itself should make it work. Inside of `%str()` you have to have a `%` sign in front of unpaired quote marks so it should look like this

`%let logfolder = %str(%"C:\Users\doe_j\folder\sub-folder1\sub folder2\subfolder3 &yr.\q&qtr.\logs%");`

Then you only need one set of quotes in the X statement

`x "if not exist &logfolder.\ mkdir -p &logfolder.";`

Answer (score 1):

Macro quoting can cause issues as well as prevent them. You should probably only apply the macro quoting where you know you need it. Unless your directory names have unbalanced quotes there is no need for macro quoting in your program.

```
%let qtr= 2 ;
%let yr= 2012 ;
%let logout=program_name_&yr.&qtr._&sysdate ;
%let logfolder=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\sub-folder1\sub folder2 space\year &yr\q&qtr\logs;
%let logname=&logfolder\&logout..log;

x %sysfunc(quote(if not exist "&logfolder" mkdir "&logfolder"));
```